# Grails RestClient accessing POST response XML

Tags: xml, rest, grails, groovy

I'm using Groovy's [RESTClient()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/RESTClient.html#post(java.util.Map)) to perform a POST with some XML as the payload to a URL. The response I expect back is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.foo.bar.net/">
            <return>
                <ip>1.1.1.1</ip>
                <platform>112</platform>
                <pop>ABC</pop>
                <site>LIP</site>
                <state>STATUS</state>
                <userId>ID1234</userId>
            </return>
        </ns2:getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I've curled to the URL and know that the response is correct, so it's not an issue with the data that comes back. My issue is the format in which `RESTClient().post().getData()` returns. If I do

```
def restClient = new RESTClient("www.someRestService.com", 'text/xml')

String soapRequest = """XML Payload..."""

def restClientResponse = restClient.post(body: soapRequest).getData()

log.info("RESPONSE: " + restClientResponse)
log.info("BODY: " + restClientResponse.Body.getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse.return.userId)
log.info("BODY T: " + restClientResponse.Body.getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse.return.userId.text())
log.info("NETWORK: " + restClientResponse.getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse.return.userId)
log.info("NETWORK T: " + restClientResponse.getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse.return.userId.text())
log.info("RETURN: " + restClientResponse.return.userId)
log.info("RETURN T: " + restClientResponse.return.userId.text())
log.info("USERID: " + restClientResponse.userId)
log.info("USERID T: " + restClientResponse.userId.text())
log.info("CHILDREN SIZE: " + restClientResponse.children().size())
log.info("CLASS: " + restClientResponse.getClass().getName())
```

What is logged is:

```
RESPONSE: 1.1.1.1112ABCLIPSTATUSID1234
BODY:
BODY T:
NETWORK:
NETWORK T:
RETURN:
RETURN T:
USERID:
USERID T:
CHILDREN SIZE: 1
CLASS: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
```

So `getData()` seems to just be returning all the text nodes instead of a parsed XML Object, which I'm sure I read somewhere that `getData()` parses XML using `XMLSlurper()`. I read [this](http://marc.info/?l=groovy-user&m=127231413219292) article among many others which seems exactly like my issue, but the answer given is exactly what I'm doing isn't it? Am I accessing `restClientResponse` in the totally wrong way?

Comment: Is worth noting, you are using a REST client to access a SOAP service. There are SOAP specific tools to do this easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

I'm an idiot!

### Medium answer

The design document I was working off outlined the XML to be expected back from the REST call is the XML I included in the question, however in reality one of the XML tags was slightly different in the real response. The `<ns2:getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse/>` was actually `<ns2:getNetworkSessionsForIPResponse/>`; even though I curled the REST client and compared the responses I was snow blind in my frustration as to what was wrong. If your having a similar issue double check then double check again the XML your actually working with.

I trawled through the `RESTClient` source code on github before I figured out what I had done wrong; in reference to @jalopaba answer an [`XMLSlurper()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#XmlSlurper()) without any constructor args is used when parsing XML, so '*a non-validating and non-namespace-aware XmlSlurper*' is created when an XML response is [parsed](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/855e1784be8585de81cc3c99fd19285798c7bc4f/src/main/java/groovyx/net/http/ParserRegistry.java#L264)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the internal XML slurping that `RESTClient` performs internally with `XmlSlurper` is [*non namespace aware*](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#XmlSlurper(boolean,%20boolean)):

So that,

```groovy
def restClientResponse = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText('''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.foo.bar.net/">
            <return>
                <ip>1.1.1.1</ip>
                <platform>112</platform>
                <pop>ABC</pop>
                <site>LIP</site>
                <state>STATUS</state>
                <userId>ID1234</userId>
            </return>
        </ns2:getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>''')

println restClientResponse
def userId
userId = restClientResponse.Body.getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse.return.userId
println "${userId.size()}: [${userId.text()}]"
userId = restClientResponse.'S:Body'.'ns2:getNetworkSessionsForUsernameResponse'.return.userId
println "${userId.size()}: [${userId.text()}]"
```

The above yields:

```
1.1.1.1112ABCLIPSTATUSID1234
0: []
1: [ID1234]
```

(Changing to a *namespace-aware* `XmlSlurper` the result is just the opposite).